# What is the year when Lord Rama was born?

Tags: vishnu, rama, hanuman

This is my wish that I want to know that year when Shri Rama was born.

Comment: 10 th January,5114 BC to be exact.This is as per the findings of ISERVE(Institute for Scientific Research on Vedas).

Comment: Rickross,I don't believe in sceintific research!